# nebulad thread crashed on iPhone 5 with EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) exception

Tags: crash, iphone

Can someone help me figure out this crash report please?

I have a ton of crashes from `"app_name":"nebulad"`.

Here is the report:

```
{"app_name":"nebulad","share_with_app_devs":false,"name":"nebulad","app_version":"","is_first_party":true,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.4 (12H143)","bug_type":"109","slice_uuid":"39a805bd-ba52-3142-a912-450ff8700784","build_version":""}
Incident Identifier: 09B69120-F052-47DE-955E-1EED10E75EBE
CrashReporter Key:   f311dd25e58ac55f465ad1a3cf33029a477059d9
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
Process:             nebulad [4499]
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/Support/nebulad
Identifier:          nebulad
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2015-08-29 16:54:25.807 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-08-21 15:47:33.111 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  2
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x28b38fea 0x3747cc86 0x275faf58 0x275faa1a 0x275fa98c 0x2dacc40e 0x2daca9d4 0x2da86836 0x2da856c4 0x2da845ce 0x2da83ce2 0x37a0d2de 0x37a15724 0x37a0faa8 0x37a16f9a 0x37a183be 0x37b74dbc 0x37b74b10)
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ae5474 0x37ae4000 + 5236
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ae5268 0x37ae4000 + 4712
2   CoreFoundation                  0x28afe56e 0x28a31000 + 841070
3   CoreFoundation                  0x28afcb14 0x28a31000 + 834324
4   CoreFoundation                  0x28a491fc 0x28a31000 + 98812
5   CoreFoundation                  0x28a4900e 0x28a31000 + 98318
6   Foundation                      0x297b3138 0x297a8000 + 45368
7   Foundation                      0x29801220 0x297a8000 + 365088
8   nebulad                         0x0009e708 0x98000 + 26376
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x37a2eaac 0x37a2d000 + 6828
Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ae5224 0x37ae4000 + 4644
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37a1a0ec 0x37a0c000 + 57580
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37a0ed36 0x37a0c000 + 11574
Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.camera.timelapse.backend.work
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37af8df0 0x37ae4000 + 85488
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b77cc2 0x37b74000 + 15554
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37a94904 0x37a4a000 + 305412
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d9b9c4 0x36d9b000 + 2500
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36db566c 0x36d9b000 + 108140
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3747cf22 0x37476000 + 28450
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36db2de0 0x36d9b000 + 97760
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36db25a4 0x36d9b000 + 95652
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3747cd5a 0x37476000 + 27994
9   AVFoundation                    0x275faf58 0x275a9000 + 335704
10  AVFoundation                    0x275faa1a 0x275a9000 + 334362
11  AVFoundation                    0x275fa98c 0x275a9000 + 334220
12  CameraKit                       0x2dacc40e 0x2da63000 + 431118
13  CameraKit                       0x2daca9d4 0x2da63000 + 424404
14  CameraKit                       0x2da86836 0x2da63000 + 145462
15  CameraKit                       0x2da856c4 0x2da63000 + 140996
16  CameraKit                       0x2da845ce 0x2da63000 + 136654
17  CameraKit                       0x2da83ce4 0x2da63000 + 134372
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x37a0d2e0 0x37a0c000 + 4832
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x37a15724 0x37a0c000 + 38692
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x37a0faa8 0x37a0c000 + 15016
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x37a16f9c 0x37a0c000 + 44956
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x37a183be 0x37a0c000 + 50110
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74dbe 0x37b74000 + 3518
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74b10 0x37b74000 + 2832
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37af99c0 0x37ae4000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74e38 0x37b74000 + 3640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74b10 0x37b74000 + 2832
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37af99c0 0x37ae4000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74e38 0x37b74000 + 3640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37b74b10 0x37b74000 + 2832
Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x00493000      r6: 0x3a480840      r7: 0x00491c08
    r8: 0x166703f0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x16670414
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x00491bfc      lr: 0x37b77cc7      pc: 0x37af8df0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
Binary Images:
0x98000 - 0x9ffff nebulad armv7s  <39a805bdba523142a912450ff8700784>/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/Support/nebulad0x1fe18000 - 0x1fe3bfff dyld armv7s<89c8b5de05ef310e9c399d3abd699990> /usr/lib/dyld
0x275a9000 - 0x27716fff AVFoundation armv7s  <194a49546fc93e0d804440a70c033fa4>/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x27717000 - 0x27776fff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <1d4dcaa02bd3375397daf4ffa2cf24cf>/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x277b0000 - 0x277b0fff Accelerate armv7s  <2c29c5379fe43440b43aff96d73855ae>/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x277c1000 - 0x279dcfff vImage armv7s  <603d854d418a39559bdfb5ec78b509bd>/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x279dd000 - 0x27ac3fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <0834c18b8b2435bc9a1a0b9019ab2c7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x27ac4000 - 0x27d88fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <417a0b8d8dd636d499919893aeb6c258> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x27d89000 - 0x27d9afff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7s  <ab870bd429bb32808ed43ee4d77b8637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x27d9b000 - 0x27e17fff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <3599c8eb992c302a9573108f9d7cb1b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x27e18000 - 0x27e2afff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <9cc618389310324caa99bba4cee6b56e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x27e2b000 - 0x27e2bfff vecLib armv7s  <6f2f59c102323ed0b1559f7523fcf7a5>/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x27e2c000 - 0x27e53fff Accounts armv7s  <ed90e206502e3b8194d1376d49c5ba45> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x27e55000 - 0x27ec3fff AddressBook armv7s  <bd5e60f1c16631d1b60d18408b400c33>/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x28184000 - 0x283fafff AudioToolbox armv7s  <b66e842e47e539bb88a12a822fd7d140> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x28569000 - 0x286f7fff CFNetwork armv7s  <2951ef2326d0314bbcfeb74c998d97de> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x2877e000 - 0x287ddfff CoreAudio armv7s  <c05e804e63713ad09b4a3e7f01d9ae3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x287f9000 - 0x28816fff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <f26779d9ff14383c98d0136fd2464928> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x28817000 - 0x28a30fff CoreData armv7s  <6345ddd864c134819e401ae3aef8aa4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x28a31000 - 0x28d60fff CoreFoundation armv7s  <b0f9be4f9a9b385eae69b5253766c059> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x28d61000 - 0x28e8bfff CoreGraphics armv7s  <dc028ef8332c32379ae76f7683203a31> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x290dc000 - 0x291eefff CoreImage armv7s  <bd7584cea4e83ce9864d1cd4d472b357> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x291ef000 - 0x29247fff CoreLocation armv7s  <92b306f81c0c3e62ba245b30fffffa32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x29279000 - 0x29317fff CoreMedia armv7s  <ad1c5626945a332ca9b622cab55cfbea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x29318000 - 0x293f6fff CoreMotion armv7s  <ad67325e00ec3b8282e0084bdc0181fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x293f7000 - 0x29455fff CoreTelephony armv7s  <1643e6cc632d3a7294b35ca7532c0ce0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x29456000 - 0x29523fff CoreText armv7s  <5daeb8eeda773123876f69556af328a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x29524000 - 0x2953afff CoreVideo armv7s  <a08f911da9913989a5296823589d1c83> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x297a8000 - 0x299adfff Foundation armv7s  <e1cf3fff076130feac7c4c9d12f1a034> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x299ae000 - 0x299d9fff GLKit armv7s  <7a03ce6aec903c5eb458676b89797fc5> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
0x29aae000 - 0x29b03fff IOKit armv7s  <0b6ea15b7a9e33369f74594e4f4296f7> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x29b04000 - 0x29d4dfff ImageIO armv7s  <c7067c86f9ee30bfaefa2cff9019bf1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x29d4e000 - 0x2a09dfff JavaScriptCore armv7s  <efad8621afbb39a79ab3d25700ff7dc7>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x2a399000 - 0x2a3a1fff MediaAccessibility armv7s  <619d9e5693a4317c8d192a2d8eb33004> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x2a5bd000 - 0x2a91cfff MediaToolbox armv7s  <ec345623fd133ca597ac8c70efbf6300> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x2a9dd000 - 0x2aa4cfff Metal armv7s  <d483e92c66a93e5f83449b097bb81cfd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x2aa4d000 - 0x2aae1fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <c4f13de01fb03ced8c949aed7fba5b6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x2b686000 - 0x2b68efff OpenGLES armv7s  <2b23e3858ee734dcb09f91a65d6790a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x2b690000 - 0x2b690fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <b863d6f98a4f3fd7aa91538edf1114a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x2b691000 - 0x2b693fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7s  <9ed06544f2f4306a8a19e6eb01e0cf82> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x2b694000 - 0x2b697fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <863f9085c99e3002844ab7edba2df248> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x2b698000 - 0x2b6a0fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <1e530b01bcc33aa5a47e4aff53273886> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x2b6a1000 - 0x2b6e3fff libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <2deb95c9596d3e97aceb2bf16fb9a120> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x2bbba000 - 0x2bd18fff QuartzCore armv7s  <b387937277b83f3c80fb4507fc84ec88> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x2bf4e000 - 0x2bf9bfff Security armv7s  <fc81feb3f2773cb8b281f674bcff953a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x2c147000 - 0x2c1a3fff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <b3b054b95f9d3b71b6cd0f07473ed29d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x2c1a6000 - 0x2ca54fff UIKit armv7s  <f55bfdaf0eb635f1997fb7d1d2b85232> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x2ca55000 - 0x2cabcfff VideoToolbox armv7s  <8015837cb2bf3aeb860666174a22fdcb> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x2cfd8000 - 0x2cffcfff ACTFramework armv7s  <906e3d75e1173d66a5257a18b0f04efa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
0x2d1e5000 - 0x2d1e9fff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <9aca854407eb3cd6be2eef702e1cafc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x2d392000 - 0x2d395fff AirPlaySupport armv7s  <8e9b0e143e9a31fd9c34e7df8cb97e8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x2d5ad000 - 0x2d5ebfff AppSupport armv7s  <c778dbc86e59350194298d94305b3f72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x2d72f000 - 0x2d76dfff AppleJPEG armv7s  <01f060587f77375b953d702a8dbca255> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x2d78b000 - 0x2d791fff AppleSRP armv7s  <6e54f8bff0e23757b824e8b58f368da2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x2d7c6000 - 0x2d7cffff AssertionServices armv7s  <54d3c722e53d3edc8d5872f2e85303b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x2d7d0000 - 0x2d7eafff AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <1e0da827a2f233d4b2a2456e17562cd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x2d852000 - 0x2d854fff BTLEAudioController armv7s  <3030948e4931378aa39637af52e9a940> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x2d855000 - 0x2d86dfff BackBoardServices armv7s  <7d45f0212c203b4cbcf03c791a72a6f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x2d870000 - 0x2d8a5fff BaseBoard armv7s  <cea92b96e1223c27be8bc1922065a323> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x2d8ef000 - 0x2d95cfff BulletinBoard armv7s  <d224982196f23a279cfb227ee4937785> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x2da63000 - 0x2db3bfff CameraKit armv7s  <2e36a4c4335a37e3a30f3c3e9fea212f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/CameraKit
0x2db3c000 - 0x2db44fff CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <fa05bd3c036c382bbd6a98579802975a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x2db4d000 - 0x2dc71fff Celestial armv7s  <d75aba0df1d13c6b8c0f5c140b5f42c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x2e348000 - 0x2e358fff CommonUtilities armv7s  <e61e9b9ccd1736d2a2769de042106ef6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x2e359000 - 0x2e35dfff CommunicationsFilter armv7s  <6620ea10781c3482808d5d2c01fd38b7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x2e45e000 - 0x2e465fff CoreAUC armv7s  <9ac0ae21bbd4302d8f5b3ef1470eacfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x2e4e7000 - 0x2e509fff CoreDuet armv7s  <cebade5bc2c631cdb6d77c86a22b812c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x2e50f000 - 0x2e51ffff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol armv7s  <8824b64ad6663eefab1e204dc714f6c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x2e526000 - 0x2e528fff CoreDuetDebugLogging armv7s  <a14a1a3e6e2535718195885e1392a0af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x2eb34000 - 0x2eb3afff CoreTime armv7s  <ab5aee28a9c830e2baa94ee402177e7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x2eb3b000 - 0x2ebbdfff CoreUI armv7s  <c9bb76b530b7355691317502d71853bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x2ebbe000 - 0x2ec43fff CoreUtils armv7s  <72b6db57b10134fa98c695e3433e221f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x2ec44000 - 0x2ec49fff CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <2a67a534bf953adbb50ee1d90b7f6d68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x2ec50000 - 0x2ec5afff DCIMServices armv7s  <be9c20ad528a3969be2cd00de0136993> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DCIMServices.framework/DCIMServices
0x2ee93000 - 0x2eeb4fff DataAccessExpress armv7s  <de55f5fbab113901809559e0c45cc379> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x2eef2000 - 0x2eef8fff DataMigration armv7s  <1cdcbd7886d73fcc9302b84b24768fda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x2ef0e000 - 0x2ef0ffff DiagnosticLogCollection armv7s  <1bfca407a8763842b26876d9d3a4bdbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x2ef10000 - 0x2ef2afff DictionaryServices armv7s  <262658cbc26535b58fccf562bd3f3540> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x2ef49000 - 0x2ef68fff EAP8021X armv7s  <345177e58f513df0adf5921d3b0f8965> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x2f0a9000 - 0x2f4ccfff FaceCore armv7s  <f43675e3ca2b30e38af583bd65bfb11d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x2f538000 - 0x2f538fff FontServices armv7s  <aa4d8b82d36c32febb27c05d087fd501> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x2f539000 - 0x2f60efff libFontParser.dylib armv7s  <04e156e95cba3afcbf362b185bb2a6a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x2f702000 - 0x2f71efff FrontBoardServices armv7s  <7832bf2520ed3b5b9c08b9db2f4397fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x3024e000 - 0x30510fff GeoServices armv7s  <059f935c2408314db191d7c345cf5bd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30511000 - 0x30521fff GraphicsServices armv7s  <d3f666dec8f93003b8d926bdfb60a83f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3085f000 - 0x308befff IDS armv7s  <e10cc706471d3e8ba06d2b5e0b5ef4a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x308bf000 - 0x308eafff IDSFoundation armv7s  <58e7fbdd225d3d51badd98c8d11f397e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x30aa1000 - 0x30b05fff IMFoundation armv7s  <c4be2028998639b29544be2fe24e0371> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x30b0d000 - 0x30b10fff IOAccelerator armv7s  <cce2894f2f66340c87931115d54310c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x30b13000 - 0x30b19fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <9ff44503801731cb8e6ac84669cd6886> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30b1a000 - 0x30b1ffff IOSurface armv7s  <5b0f3d524f3d35cebd1f5cf58812289a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x30b20000 - 0x30b21fff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7s  <47f0ce0daf7b385dbd05cc945ab8aca3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x30e29000 - 0x30e2efff IncomingCallFilter armv7s  <589e77c550b23898a5df27d344805d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IncomingCallFilter.framework/IncomingCallFilter
0x30e36000 - 0x30e6ffff LanguageModeling armv7s  <1ed3b9c3fb603352b1222717421ef22d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x31033000 - 0x310d4fff ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <bce75ce48f5b342c9a273c464d50566b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x310e3000 - 0x310e4fff Marco armv7s  <d6ab30ff7a083b69a5d820ef30068943> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x310e5000 - 0x31147fff MediaControlSender armv7s  <fae4abd65cbe3120b6ed13fb12f2137f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x31256000 - 0x3126bfff MediaRemote armv7s  <59648fcb11c43e46a3142e4daabaa506> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x3126c000 - 0x31280fff MediaServices armv7s  <229c69fd7494379dae3a37ecc50c8156> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaServices.framework/MediaServices
0x3144d000 - 0x3145afff MobileAsset armv7s  <0cf05f42ea2631bea5b98fc3813d54a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x314b0000 - 0x314b7fff MobileInstallation armv7s  <744678393e0a369d835d45122aa1c39a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x314b8000 - 0x314c4fff MobileKeyBag armv7s  <164a8992e73130bb93d718a70f01508e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x314f1000 - 0x314f4fff MobileSystemServices armv7s  <5fe21fe36f3a339c9a4c1b5fc40cb00c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x31517000 - 0x31524fff MobileWiFi armv7s  <5f50f36b874633558060b118ea38f771> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x318a7000 - 0x318acfff Netrb armv7s  <4855526152cc3affb6db50b11092acc3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x318ad000 - 0x318b3fff NetworkStatistics armv7s  <81bab06aec6e39b3b891445519d7da2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x318d2000 - 0x318d6fff NotificationsUI armv7s  <99b5e7fdda6f34528abfb38e2941b086> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NotificationsUI.framework/NotificationsUI
0x318d7000 - 0x318d9fff OAuth armv7s  <64c7011a67c13088a5de0039ef676226> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x3203d000 - 0x32079fff OpenCL armv7s  <bd6504e67fff330897805d7244bdb525> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x32200000 - 0x32227fff PersistentConnection armv7s  <12bd6d97d19233b198244222fcd661cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3264a000 - 0x32694fff PhysicsKit armv7s  <5fbe8c4942643422957809bbe7b70ce5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x326ac000 - 0x326b3fff PowerLog armv7s  <04d4a85d18343b49967f2715896f21bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x329ac000 - 0x329affff ProgressUI armv7s  <f5e49ef79d6f3d818c171f496d83b924> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProgressUI.framework/ProgressUI
0x329b0000 - 0x32a47fff ProofReader armv7s  <41af3fc884683f03881f4bca035b6cff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32a6a000 - 0x32a76fff ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <9fc87ead0dea3e5ba388128a061ee685> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32a77000 - 0x32aa8fff PrototypeTools armv7s  <5379ff9532763a3680b7a259b709b9a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrototypeTools.framework/PrototypeTools
0x32aab000 - 0x32b1afff Quagga armv7s  <6ff484b6ac27377ea50dcf701ed58289> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x3307d000 - 0x330b0fff SpringBoardFoundation armv7s  <31522dba78ad3f829092b1b16744b104> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardFoundation.framework/SpringBoardFoundation
0x330b1000 - 0x330cbfff SpringBoardServices armv7s  <e992a59dc7913dbe97b7b598d5c5142c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x330cc000 - 0x330defff SpringBoardUI armv7s  <f19570821a5c35de9061bc65feed68e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x330df000 - 0x33102fff SpringBoardUIServices armv7s  <025128cbcc3237a4b93e5542c89f2b42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUIServices.framework/SpringBoardUIServices
0x334f1000 - 0x33672fff StoreServices armv7s  <da560e251f0d361d8136484aec0b5842> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3374f000 - 0x33752fff TCC armv7s  <a232868567b839409e8da65573f7c05f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x33760000 - 0x337a5fff TelephonyUI armv7s  <4b1f91ce35013fd9bddf2c5e190c3d4a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x337a6000 - 0x337ecfff TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <94fd0cab4da13934a948d8c64e0d4e30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x343b0000 - 0x343d8fff TextInput armv7s  <32f81265e88833c6938da2d33639fef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3441e000 - 0x3443cfff ToneLibrary armv7s  <4a4c1fbe841f3714a213c9dd32cf25b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/ToneLibrary
0x34499000 - 0x3455bfff UIFoundation armv7s  <2f9dc342c2aa3d7997ed79e8287a477a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x34582000 - 0x34585fff UserFS armv7s  <bb323f5c243f382c85a9c526462941c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x34e04000 - 0x35991fff WebCore armv7s  <86ab910f7d9137c189d6b3091a858b74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x35992000 - 0x35a50fff WebKitLegacy armv7s  <c437005fc8e53fd3b2698aab7ca2a778> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x3671e000 - 0x36726fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <a5bd0c884f4e379ca628a68bec7761a4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3697a000 - 0x36990fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <97cb66e992213474952636ac4c1e2964> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x369c6000 - 0x36acafff libFosl_dynamic.dylib armv7s  <555694b4096a31a997eff8e02b3aa95f> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x36ae4000 - 0x36afbfff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <2f510b053a8d35bf93bc48bbcc674eed> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x36afc000 - 0x36b04fff libMobileGestaltExtensions.dylib armv7s  <2e6213e3510234b89800b5afe345c43a> /usr/lib/libMobileGestaltExtensions.dylib
0x36b21000 - 0x36b22fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <17ed31282e163c118455134a7b7f646d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36b93000 - 0x36bd7fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7s  <760ea1422fb1389f8fd95fec30c9f421> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x36ce7000 - 0x36d09fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7s  <541276010c9f30548f857a04f773c2a4> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x36d39000 - 0x36d45fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <9cfd51d1581830a792d0cb1b23af4095> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36d46000 - 0x36d4ffff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <31dee871cf5d3f8f9087ae3ffccdbe23> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x36d50000 - 0x36d9afff libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <9334c8bd200c345bb1eef72019faa356> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x36d9b000 - 0x36db6fff libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <0026c16a32e339cb8898ddad041592e4> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36db8000 - 0x36dc5fff libcmph.dylib armv7s  <e7f8c46d1309360d87fab965066bd576> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x36df5000 - 0x36e0efff libextension.dylib armv7s  <7a90b66679ec354abfbec00b774be34b> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x36e31000 - 0x36f1efff libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <d3d45de2a6b238fa9919d990fbe1d3d9> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36f1f000 - 0x3708dfff libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <8574af1687933d1caee7fc2a51f04e4f> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3709a000 - 0x3709afff liblangid.dylib armv7s
```

Comment: Is this an app you've written yourself or something you've bought?

Comment: This is impossible to read. Please format in a way that allows people to help you. Also give more information on how often this occurs, and what the app is doing when it crashes and whether you tried to get rid of the app and reinstall it.

Comment: @oarfish already done - with >600 rep you should know that we help First Poster with formatting. 

Do you have an App called `Nebulad` installed on your Phone? Can you tell us which Kind of App it is?

Comment: No I do not have this app on my phone I also googled it and could not find what app it could corespond to. It has showed up 14 times from August 12-29. I do not know how to write apps (I wish) so no it's not an app I have written. Also my phone is not jail broken (that I know of lol) coretime has also logged a crash a day since August 14. I don't know what that is either. My phone has been really glitchy and weird the past bit. I am sorry about not posting it properly as I am a first time user to this site. Not meaning to offend anyone :)

Comment: How would I format it to be readable for future posting? Thank you

Comment: @SarahLaing, no worries about the formatting. That was taken care of. I suggest that you wipe and restore your phone. Make sure it is backed up and then erase all content and settings from it. Then restore it - preferably from iCloud as that is the easiest, likely.

Comment: What is the app though? Has someone jail broken my phone without me knowing? And is it spy wear ? Or is the to James Bond and paranoid lol?

Comment: The web doesn't seem to have many useful answers, based on the naming and location, I assume it's a daemon process (name ends in 'd' and was spawned the the launchd daemon) that controls some form of iCloud uploading (it's named 'nebula', get it?). The fact that is was called with SIGABRT probably means it was [some third party's crappy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536276/how-to-diagnose-exc-crash). I'd restore the phone as others have suggested, and think carefully about any camera/cloud apps you may have installed.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Do you think my phone has been jail broken? Or it is spyware?

Comment: Your clue is the line `Path: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/Support/nebulad`. The program `nebulad` would appear to be part of the CameraKit framework. I couldn't find any specific information on `nebulad`, but that in itself is not suspicious (many such support programs and daemons on iOS and OS X are not publicly documented, unless used directly by developers, typically). There is also a line mentioning a crash in the `com.apple.camera.timelapse.backend.work` thread. Those two items **might** point to some issue with CameraKit-related 3rd party hardware, or time-lapse.

Answer (score 1):

The crash report says that `nebulad` crashed with `SIGABRT` signal on your iPhone device (iOS 8.4).

The [SIGABRT signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) is usually send to a process to tell it to abort/terminate by calling [`abort()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_process_control#abort) (abnormal program termination without cleaning up). This can happen in case of critical errors.

This is usually related to some seriously broken constraint. For example `malloc()` calls `abort()` if its internal structures are damaged by a heap overflow or there is a problem with memory allocation.<sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413215/55075)</sup>

Therefore the crash could be related to memory issue, software bug or some hardware issue.

The suggestions are to:

- Reboot the device to free up the memory.
- Upgrade your iOS (since the process is part of `CameraKit` framework which comes with iOS).
- If it's keep repeating, [report the bug at Apple site](https://bugreport.apple.com).